# How to delete all "one-to-many" items in a ColdFusion orm entity?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
var items = job.getItems();
for (var item in items)
    job.removeItem(item);
```

And CF / Java throws

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>     at
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)

What's the cleanest way to remove all items without `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Thank you!

Comment: Access them via array index using a for or while loop, or if that isn't possible, copy them into a temporary list, and iterate over that list.  I don't know java (hence jobs, etc), but I know how enumerations work :)

Comment: oh FYI, job is just a CF component `Job.cfc` with persistent=true, not something in Java.

Comment: Yep, and hence why it is correct that you accepted Peter's answer.  However, the error you are getting has to do with deleting from a collection you are currently iterating over, which is a more generic problem in Java.  He seems to state the `clear` method isn't always available.  If you see this in other contexts, and don't have a `clear` method, try one of the work-arounds I mentioned.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A java List has an (optional) **clear()** method.

The code would then become :

```
 job.getItems().clear()
```

AFAICS coldfusion9 uses hibernate as ORM, and hibernate does implement clear on the List abstraction, and will even translate it to a single DELETE statement to the database.

Comment: +1, since this would be the best option (if available).  What if this option isn't available?  Or is it definitely available for "job"...

Comment: Hibernate supports it, JPA 1.0 specs it, ... I would be surprised if it were not supported.

Comment: Awesome, I forgot there's ArrayClear() in ColdFusion that calls .clear() in the Java.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Inside job.cfc, must implement a method that clears the items.

```
boolean function emptyItems()
{
    return arrayClear(variables.items);
}
```

And then...

```
job.emptyItems();
```

ColdFusion's `arrayClear()` would call `clear()` in Java underneath.

That's the only way 'cause Array in ColdFusion is **passed-by-value**.  Therefore, clearing it after getItems() does nothing to `job.items`.  Silly me.